# Uploading an image from UIImagePickerController using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload an image to a server using Alamofire. When I use the following everything works correctly with a test image saved in the bundle.

```
    func uploadImage()
{
    let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Uploadtest", withExtension: "jpg")
    Alamofire.upload(.PUT, url + "/api/Image" + id, file: fileURL!).responseString {
        _, _, result in
        print("Success: \(result.isSuccess)")
        print("Response String: \(result.value)")
    }
}
```

However, I wish to upload an image from UIImagePickerController. The Alamofire upload method takes a file url as a parameter, while I get an instance of UIImage back from the UIImagePickerController. Should I save this image locally to documents or similar and then get a url to that location to pass in to the Alamofire upload method? is this possible or is there another way I missing?

Comment: In your `UIImagePickerDelegate` you will need to utilize the 

    optional func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

The info dictionary that is returned to you has a key which should be what your need `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`

Comment: Thanks JMFR that looks good, though for some reason info has no values in it. I'm sure that's something I'm doing wrong though!

Comment: I think you may be right that the best way is to save a local copy. Then upload that. (I am guessing this is because of sandboxing, we can't just get the url of the file in the photos app. Since they have their own directory of data, separate from our apps data.)

Comment: Write up an answer to your own question. And I will give it a :thumbsup:

Comment: Will do, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I did the following, which is working.

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]
    {
        print(imageURL)
        Alamofire.upload(.PUT, url + "/api/Image/" + id, file: imageURL).responseString {
            _, _, result in
            print("Success: \(result.isSuccess)")
            print("Response String: \(result.value)")
        }
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```